# Styling a Bootstrap based component

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

We currently have an ASPX CMS website which is being partially retired, and those retired pages will be running from a new (non-cms) website (on a subdomain).
The new website will be using Bootstrap 4.6 (the existing CMS site is all custom CSS - no framework\libraries) - so i'm presently grabbing different sections of the website & building them using bootstrap.

I'm currently trying to build this section ('Speakers'), but am running into some problems - which i think is because of the approach im currently taking.
Im trying to build this (red horizontal line isn't part of it... i just included it as it spans the screen width as an idea to padding)
[image]

and this is what my current attempt is looking like (and why im asking for help)
[image]

And here's my current HTML

```
<div class="row pt-4 mt-1 pb-4">
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <div class="container-fluid ceda-event-box pl-0 pb-5">
                <h2 class="mt-5 pr-1 pl-5 pt-4 bg-ceda-darkblue"><br></h2>
                <p><br></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here's the current CSS classes i have (I'm using Bootstrap 4.6)... some of this i copied from the existing site CSS - mainly just trying to make sure i had the same gradient grey, and also for the SVG image (which the dots are)

```
.ceda-event-box::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc((100% - 100vw) / 2);
    right: 54px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
}

.ceda-event-box::before {
    background: linear-gradient(64.15deg, #f3f3f3 50.52%, #bfbfbf 100%);
    z-index: -1;
}

.ceda-event-box >p::before,
.ceda-event-box .b-box::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 127px;
    height: 98px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    right: 68px;
}

.bg-ceda-darkblue {
     background-color: #252932;
     border-color: #252932;
}
```

Any suggestions for better bootstrap components to use - or a better way to build it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the element `position: absolute` and then add its ***top***, ***left*** and ***right*** properties accordingly. As long as you match the ***right*** property that defines where the grey background is in relation to its elements ***right*** property, which I believe is `.ceda-event-box::before`, then the blue element will align properly as they are both absolute and bubbling back up to their closest parents relative property.

```css
:root {
  --top: 4px;
  --height: 98px;
}

.ceda-event-box::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc((100% - 100vw) / 2);
    right: 54px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.ceda-event-box::before {
    background: linear-gradient(64.15deg, #f3f3f3 50.52%, #bfbfbf 100%);
    z-index: -1;
}

.ceda-event-box >p::before,
.ceda-event-box .b-box::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 127px;
    height: var(--height);
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
    position: absolute;
    top: var(--top);
    right: 68px;
}

.bg-ceda-darkblue {
     background-color: #252932;
     border-color: #252932;
     position: absolute;
     margin: 0; /* reset any margin on this element */
     top: calc(102px / 2);
     left: 0;
     right: 54px;
     height: calc(var(--height) + var(--top) - calc(102px / 2));
}
```

```html
<div class="row pt-4 mt-1 pb-4">
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <div class="container-fluid ceda-event-box pl-0 pb-5">
                <h2 class="mt-5 pr-1 pl-5 pt-4 bg-ceda-darkblue"></h2>
                <p><br></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you want the bottom of the blue element to be in line with the bottom of the gradient: `.ceda-event-box::before` then you can set the bottom property of the blue element the same, again using a css variable will do this nicely. I have added a 20% bottom buffer on the two elements to show how this would work.

```css
:root {
  --top: 4px;
  --height: 98px;
  --bottom: 20%;
}

.ceda-event-box::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc((100% - 100vw) / 2);
  right: 54px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: var(--bottom);
}

.ceda-event-box::before {
  background: linear-gradient(64.15deg, #f3f3f3 50.52%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.ceda-event-box>p::before,
.ceda-event-box .b-box::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 127px;
  height: var(--height);
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--top);
  right: 68px;
}

.bg-ceda-darkblue {
  background-color: #252932;
  border-color: #252932;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  /* reset any margin on this element */
  top: calc(102px / 2);
  left: 0;
  right: 54px;
  bottom: var(--bottom);
}
```

```html
<div class="row pt-4 mt-1 pb-4">
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="container-fluid ceda-event-box pl-0 pb-5">
      <h2 class="mt-5 pr-1 pl-5 pt-4 bg-ceda-darkblue"></h2>
      <p><br></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would that align the bottom of the blue element ontop of the bottom of the gradient?
Additionally i still have to bring in the start of the blue element as it doesn't start on the very left hand side ~ and i don't think padding or margins would help there, as obviously it all has to be responsive.
at the moment i think it needs to be implemented in a different way... like maybe not using rows\columns & instead using containers.

Comment: So your gradient, is `ceda-event-box` which has a ***top position of 4px;*** and a ***height of 98px***, you can simply make the bottom of the blue element a height of the calculation of those measurements - its top position. `height: calc(98px + 4px - 55px);` ***55px*** is the top position of the blue element. This will align the bottom of the blue element with the bottom of the gradient.

Comment: @BlissSol If you want the bottom of the blue element to be in line with the bottom of the gradient: .ceda-event-box::before then you can set the bottom property of the blue element the same, see my updated snippit.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up re-writing it in a different approach, which i think is better;

this is what i ended up with on desktop\large displays... some things could still be finely tuned to make it better & CSS Classnames will be changed.
[image]
HTML Code:

```
<div class="clearfix pb-4"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid float-left pl-0 pr-0 test-box mb-4">
        <div class="container-fluid float-right pt-4 test-box-title">
            <h2 class="b-heading-2 pt-4 pb-4">SPEAKERS</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid float-right pr-0 m-0 bg-ceda-darkblue text-white test-box-dark">
            <p class="p-sm-2 p-lg-5">The Hon. Dominic Perrottet MP, Treasurer of NSW<br>
                Melinda Cilento, Chief Executive, CEDA</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.test-box {
    width: 85% !important;
    background: linear-gradient(64.15deg, #f3f3f3 50.52%, #bfbfbf 100%);
    z-index: -1;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .test-box {
        width: 95% !important;
    }

    .test-box-title {
        max-width: 92% !important;
    }

    .test-box-dark {
        max-width: 90% !important;
    }
}

.test-box-title {
    max-width: 85% !important;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .test-box-title::before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        width: 127px;
        height: 98px; 
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTI3IiBoZWlnaHQ9Ijk4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTI3IDk4IiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPg0KPGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iNS41IiBjeT0iOTIuNSIgcj0iNS41IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxODAgNS41IDkyLjUpIiBmaWxsPSJ3aGl0ZSIvPg0KPGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iNS41IiBjeT0iMzQuNSIgcj0iNS41IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxODAgNS41IDM0LjUpIiBmaWxsPSJ3aGl0ZSIvPg0KPGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iNS41IiBjeT0iNjMuNSIgcj0iNS41IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxODAgNS41IDYzLjUpIiBmaWxsPSJ3aGl0ZSIvPg0KPGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iNS41IiBjeT0iNS41IiByPSI1LjUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDE4MCA1LjUgNS41KSIgZmlsbD0id2hpdGUiLz4NCjxnIG9wYWNpdHk9IjAuOCI+DQo8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIzNC41IiBjeT0iOTIuNSIgcj0iNS41IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxODAgMzQuNSA5Mi41KSIgZmlsbD0id2hpdGUiLz4NCjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjM0LjUiIGN5PSIzNC41IiByPSI1LjUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDE4MCAzNC41IDM0LjUpIiBmaWxsPSJ3aGl0ZSIvPg0KPGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMzQuNSIgY3k9IjYzLjUiIHI9IjUuNSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTgwIDM0LjUgNjMuNSkiIGZpbGw9IndoaXRlIi8+DQo8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIzNC41IiBjeT0iNS41IiByPSI1LjUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDE4MCAzNC41IDUuNSkiIGZpbGw9IndoaXRlIi8+DQo8L2c+DQo8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI2My41IiBjeT0iOTIuNSIgcj0iNS41IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxODAgNjMuNSA5Mi41KSIgZmlsbD0id2hpdGUiIGZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eT0iMC41Ii8+DQo8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI2My41IiBjeT0iMzQuNSIgcj0iNS41IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxODAgNjMuNSAzNC41KSIgZmlsbD0id2hpdGUiIGZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eT0iMC41Ii8+DQo8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI2My41IiBjeT0iNjMuNSIgcj0iNS41IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxODAgNjMuNSA2My41KSIgZmlsbD0id2hpdGUiIGZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eT0iMC41Ii8+DQo8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI2My41IiBjeT0iNS41IiByPSI1LjUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDE4MCA2My41IDUuNSkiIGZpbGw9IndoaXRlIiBmaWxsLW9wYWNpdHk9IjAuNSIvPg0KPGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iOTIuNSIgY3k9IjkyLjUiIHI9IjUuNSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTgwIDkyLjUgOTIuNSkiIGZpbGw9IndoaXRlIiBmaWxsLW9wYWNpdHk9IjAuMyIvPg0KPGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iOTIuNSIgY3k9IjM0LjUiIHI9IjUuNSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTgwIDkyLjUgMzQuNSkiIGZpbGw9IndoaXRlIiBmaWxsLW9wYWNpdHk9IjAuMyIvPg0KPGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iOTIuNSIgY3k9IjYzLjUiIHI9IjUuNSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTgwIDkyLjUgNjMuNSkiIGZpbGw9IndoaXRlIiBmaWxsLW9wYWNpdHk9IjAuMyIvPg0KPGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iOTIuNSIgY3k9IjUuNSIgcj0iNS41IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxODAgOTIuNSA1LjUpIiBmaWxsPSJ3aGl0ZSIgZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjMiLz4NCjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjEyMS41IiBjeT0iOTIuNSIgcj0iNS41IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxODAgMTIxLjUgOTIuNSkiIGZpbGw9IndoaXRlIiBmaWxsLW9wYWNpdHk9IjAuMiIvPg0KPGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMTIxLjUiIGN5PSIzNC41IiByPSI1LjUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDE4MCAxMjEuNSAzNC41KSIgZmlsbD0id2hpdGUiIGZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eT0iMC4yIi8+DQo8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxMjEuNSIgY3k9IjYzLjUiIHI9IjUuNSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTgwIDEyMS41IDYzLjUpIiBmaWxsPSJ3aGl0ZSIgZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjIiLz4NCjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjEyMS41IiBjeT0iNS41IiByPSI1LjUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDE4MCAxMjEuNSA1LjUpIiBmaWxsPSJ3aGl0ZSIgZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjIiLz4NCjwvc3ZnPg0K");
        position: relative;
        top: 70px;
        right: 40px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        float:right;
        right: 0%;
    }
}

.test-box-dark {
    max-width: 65%;
}
```